# How can I create a JSON object by getting checkboxes names and values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, query-string, querystringparameter

I'm building a script to update the url based on the checkboxes that the user selects. I found a interesting script that handles the update thing but I need to construct an object like this:

```
Object {foo: "bar", spam: "eggs", tracker: "yes"}
```

I already get the checkboxes values and push them into an array, but I don't know how to build an object similar to the above

My array looks like this in the console:

```
["brand:Brand3", "brand:Brand5", "size:Size1"]
```

This is my [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4tj03jx/) (see the output in the browser's console)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli, why voting to close? I wanted some direction on how to create the object I needed. I did not find a good resource on how to do it.

Comment: You should try to solve the problem, and then ask for help, showing the code you managed to write; this kind of question is off-topic.

Comment: Well, I did show the jsfiddle with my code. Anyway.

Comment: Don't make us go somewhere else to find your code, put it in the questions it self. A jsfiddle is always a good idea **on top** of code. Or better still use StackOverflow's CodeSnippet feature (the [<>] button in the editor) which will give us the code and working example all in one spot.

Comment: @JonP, Thanks for the useful suggestions. Didn't know about the CodeSnippet. Definitely something I will do from now on.

Comment: Did that fix the issue or is it still there?

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').on('change', function () {
    var url = document.URL;
    var addition = {};
    $('input').each(function(){
      addition[$(this).prop('name')] = $(this).val();
    });
    console.log(JSON.stringify(addition));
})
```

[Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k4tj03jx/6/)

You might need to change the selector, depending if you have more inputs on the page.